# tkinter create_image not working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to fix this bug for hours and I'm completely lost. I'm trying to draw an image to my tkinter canvas. The canvas is first created when I initialize a class using the following code:

```
self.obj = tk.Tk()
self.screen = tk.Canvas(self.obj, bg='black', height='320', width='640')
self.screen.pack()
self.pixel = tk.PhotoImage(file="pixel.gif")
self.obj.mainloop()
```

Then in a later function, I try to draw `self.pixel` to the canvas using this code:

```
 self.screen.create_image((160, 320), image=self.pixel, anchor = tk.CENTER)
```

This statement definitely executes but nothing is drawn to the canvas. When I exit out of the tkinter window the following traceback gets printed to the console:

```
File "c:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2284, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
File "c:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2275, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".43421368"
```

The name of the "invalid command" changes every time I run the program but the rest of the error message stays the same.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".43421368"` means that you are trying to call a method on a widget that has been destroyed.

The way you wrote your question, it sounds like you have code that executes *after* `mainloop()` is called and  exits. Make sure all your code executes before `mainloop()` returns.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
self.screen.create_image(160, 320, image=self.pixel, anchor = tk.CENTER)
```

Comment: Maybe this will help. I tried putting the self.screen.create_image call before the self.obj.mainloop() call. Now it's drawing the image. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Yes. All code after mainloop won't be executed before mainlooop exits, usually at the end of the program...

Comment: hmm, where should I put the mainloop() then if I need to have the screen displayed while my program is running?

Comment: You set up the gui, including commands, event handlers, and timed events, and start mainloop, the event handler.  While mainloop is running, it calls your code in response to user events (key, mouse) and timed events. There are several examples in answers to tkinter questins on SO.